# git apply does not delete\rename files

Tags: git

`enter code here`i am trying to apply a commit from one repository and apply it on other repository. to do so, i am using `git show` to generate the git patch\diff then pipe it to `git apply`.

```sh
$ git show <commit hash> | git -C ../other/repo apply
```

some of the picked commits, holds changes that delete and rename files but after `git apply` the deleted files remains. e.g., in `other/repo` there is a file named `foo.txt`, then i locate the commit that deletes the file with `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` and finally passes that commit to git apply.

how should `git apply` be executed to delete a file?

Comment: More generally, to copy a commit, use `git cherry-pick`, which *does* handle renames.

Comment: @torek: from the doc, it does not say anything about which input git-apply expects, and git-apply can detect rename https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---summary

Comment: Ah, you're right, `git apply` *does* handle renames these days. But generally cherry-pick is a better approach here.

Comment: I snipped my first comment (since it was just wrong), but I see there has not been any other response yet. You might want to build a test-case so that people can reproduce the problem easily.